# print all max values in text file using awk

Tags: awk, maximize

I'm trying to print out all the max values in one column

So the input looks like this

```
John.      Marketing.   5000.  
Marcus.    Manager.     9500.  
Jason.     SW           9500.  
Cindy.     Developer.   6000.
```

the output I want is

```
   name: Marcus, sal: 9500.    
   name: Jason, sal: 9500
```

so far, my code is

```c
    BEGIN {a=0}

    {
        if ($3> a)
           max=$3;
        output=$1
     }

    END{
      print "name: ", output, "sal:", max
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the file twice, first find the max value, then print lines with it, e.g. (assuming `max` is a positive number):

*parse.awk*

```
NR == FNR && $3  > max { max = $3 }
NR != FNR && $3 == max
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f paste.awk infile{,}
```

Add `{ print "name:", $1, "sal:", $3 }` to the last line of `parse.awk` to change the formatting, output will then be:

```
name: Marcus. sal: 9500.
name: Jason. sal: 9500.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a awk script you can do :

tst.awk

```c
!max || $3 > max {max=$3; delete array}
$3 == max {array[$0]="name:" OFS $1 OFS "sal:" OFS $3}
END{
        for(key in array){
                print array[key]
        }
}
```

That will do :

- if `max` does not exist or is less than `$3` set `max` to `$3` and delete array `array`
- if `$3` equal to `max` store in array your output
- `END` at the end of the script, for each key in `array` print it

---

You can use that script if your list of `max` value isn't to large. Otherwise [@Thor's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725072/539768) may be a better solution.